# Elm: How to add a br tag in a contenteditable div in Chrome on enter press?

Tags: html, contenteditable, elm, onkeypress

Chrome seems to add a `div` when enter key is pressed in a `contenteditable`. I'd like a `br` to always be used. There are plenty of js examples on SO (and the interwebs) but I'm new to Elm and there isn't that much information on how to do this.

I have come across this code on github:

```
onKeyPress : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onKeyPress tagger =
    on "keypress" (Decode.map tagger keyCode)
```

but am not grokking how to use the function. My view would look something like this:

```
view : Model -> Html Message
view model = div [ contentEditable True, onKeyPress SomeMessage] []
```

Message type would look like this:

```
type Message
= None
| SomeMessage Int
```

And the update would be something like:

```
update : Message -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Message )
update message model =
    case message of
        SomeMessage (Ok isThisTheKeyCode) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        SomeMessage (Err err) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

There are examples with input fields but I think those are different.

Any advice or pointing me in the right direction or filling in the gaps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Update: To be clear, I can see how this is done with JavaScript. I'm asking for assistance or direction for the Elm implementation. Thank you

Update 2: I think I'm in the right direction. My implementation actually had a div with another contentEditable inside it. The inner div was the one I was trying to get to update.

```
div [ contentEditable True][
  div [contentEditable True]
  []
]
```

I removed the inner contentEditable so now looks like

```
div [ contentEditable True][
  div [] []
]
```

Still trying to figure out how to substitute `br` for `div` in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can change default paragraph separator by [by referring this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content). But what you are trying to achieve is possible with `Shift + Enter` combination.

Comment: There are plenty of examples with JS. I'm asking for help with the Elm implementation. Also, this feature is user facing. Asking users to `Shift + Enter` (imo) is unreasonable.